# C++ abstract class inheritance virtual function

Tags: c++, oop

I have an abstract base class with some attributes or member elements and some public functions and a public pure virtual functions. In the derived class of the abstract class, I want to (a) access the members of the abstract base class as private members and (b) the public functions and defined pure virtual functions stay as public. Is there a way to do it? That is., what should be the xxxx of AbstractBase and yyyy access specifier in the derived to realize this?

```
#include <iostream>

class AbstractBase {
 xxxx: <-- // protected/private/public?
  std::string baseprivate1;

 public:
  virtual void set_privates() = 0;
  void print() { std::cout << baseprivate1 << std::endl; }
  void foo() { // some definition here }
};

class Derived : yyyy AbstractBase {  <--- //public/protected/private? 
 private:
  std::string derivedprivate1;

 public:
  void set_privates() {
    // I want this baseprivate1 to be private in derived class as well.
    // When I choose xxxx as protected and yyyy as public, the baseprivate1 is protected. 
    this->baseprivate1 = "Base private1";
    this->derivedprivate1 = "Derived private1";
  }
  void print() {
    AbstractBase::print();
    std::cout << this->derivedprivate1;
  }
  // When I choose xxxx as protected and yyyy as protected
  // foo becomes protected and unable to call from outside
  // I want the foo of abstract base to be public here as well. 
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Derived d;
    d.set_privates();
    d.print();
    d.foo(); // I should be able to call foo of abstract base class
}
```

It can be confused as duplicate of [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance). If you keep xxxx as protected and yyyy as public, then baseprivate1 will be protected in Derived and is not private anymore. Alternatively, if xxxx is public/protected and yyyy is private, the functions in derived becomes private.

Comment: plz see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance

Comment: Short answer: xxxx - protected, yyyy - public

Comment: @slava that makes baseprivate1 to be protected in derived and not private.

Comment: @RamakrishnanKannan your data should provide as low access as possible, in this case `protected` is necessary despite what you want or not.

Comment: What you want suggests a class strategy that probably was inadequately thought out. I suspect an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @UKMonkey can you please reopen the question? One of the user pinged me with the answer. He wants to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to acomplish what you want would be to use private inheritance of AbstractBase on your Derived class.  You can then expose some of AbstractBase's methods with a using-declaration under a public access specifier in the Derived class.

```
#include <iostream>

class AbstractBase {
    public:
        std::string baseprivate1;

        virtual void set_privates() = 0;
        void print() { std::cout << baseprivate1 << std::endl; }
        void foo() { /* some definition here */ }
};

class Derived : private AbstractBase { // use private inheritance on AbstractBase
    private:
        std::string derivedprivate1;

    public:
        // expose AbstractBase's methods with using-declarations
        using AbstractBase::foo;
        using AbstractBase::print;

        void set_privates() {
            this->baseprivate1 = "Base private1";
            this->derivedprivate1 = "Derived private1";
        }

        void print() {
            AbstractBase::print();
            std::cout << this->derivedprivate1 << std::endl;;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Derived d;
    d.set_privates();
    d.print();
    d.foo();
    return 0;
}
```